# Classical cryptographic key exchange

Tags: key-exchange, needham-schroeder

I am currently reviewing for my exam and a questions comes to my mind when I read an example about a simple key exchange protocol. In my textbook, the author comes up with an example about a simple key exchange which is the same as in the below image. The Needham-Schroeder, Denning-Sacco protocols are both based on this simple protocol.
[image]

My question is why C does not send session key directly to B? In my opinion, the reason is to avoid DoS attack to C. But is it the only reason?

Answer (score 0):

Why would that prevent a denial of service to C? If it were left out of the loop, that would improve performance. But C is needed as a trusted party in an unteusted network. Alice initiates the exchange, and needs a session key for B. If C were to just forward A's request, the trusted party would be useless.